# Can't redirect to the fan page or other links

Tags: php, facebook

I've made a Facebook application for an holiday site, user can login with their facebook account and vote members of a team.

When a user (logged in with his Facebook account) vote a member, a simple post is published into his wall:

```
    $wallPost = array(
        'message' => 'A simple message here',
        'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/link_to_fan_page',
    );
```

now if I click on the post on my wall, the link redirect to fan page as expected, but if a  friend or other people (who had nothing to do with the application) looking into my wall click on the link, the redirect to the fan does not happen and they got a popup error.

**An error occurred with the *application_name*. Please try again later**

The **publish_stream** permission is set correctly.

Because the redirect is not applied?

Comment: Is the application you created to enable post on wall functionality is in sand box mood?

Comment: If you mean: Developers site -> My application -> Advanced -> Authentication -> Sandbox Mode, so it is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved replacing

```
$publishStream = $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $wallPost);
```

with

```
$publishStream = $this->facebook->api('/me/links', 'post', $wallPost);
```

For more info about the **feed** and **links** take a look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/